# How to calculate the Date difference in CQL3/Cassandra

Tags: datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm Trying in the cassandra query language tool DevCenter 1.6.0 to get the date difference from existing table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built-in function in CQL - you can potentially implement [user-defined function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateFunction.html) for it, but this will require additional programming in Java, and that will also require changing the `cassandra.yaml` configuration file to enable support for user-defined functions (see linked documentation for details).